# Send the output file to a mail without changing the data

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email

I am having a output file called **result** from a script as below:

```
|first_t          |   PASS        |
|second_t       |   PASS        |
|third_t      |   File_Error  |
```

And I used the below **column** command to get the output in sequence as below:

```
column -t -s " " result > result_new

|first_t   |  PASS        |
|second_t  |  PASS        |
|third_t   |  File_Error  |
```

And after sending the **result_new** file to the mail using below **mail** command as in the below script I am not getting the expected output.

```
#!/bin/bash
mail -s "COLUMN CHECK_1"  name@gmail.com < result_new
```

I am getting this output in my mail:

```
|first_t          |   PASS        |
|second_t       |   PASS        |
|third_t      |   File_Error  |
```

My expected output in mail should be this:

```
|first_t   |  PASS        |
|second_t  |  PASS        |
|third_t   |  File_Error  |
```

Can someone tell me what should I do here?

Comment: what do you mean by '*not getting the expected output*'? are you getting an error (and if so, what error)? is the email being sent? if the email is being sent, is there an issue with the contents of the email (and if so, **WHAT** is the issue)?

Comment: @markp-fuso As shown above I'm missing my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is with the (receiving) email client and that it's displaying the message using a variable width font (eg, spaces aren't as wide as letters); to get around this issue I can think of a couple options:

- send the output as an ascii text file attachment (user would need to open the attachment with an ascii text reader - eg, `vim`, `notepad`, etc)
- format the outgoing email (eg, `MIME + 'text/html'`) so the (receiving) email client knows to display the content as fixed-width text (though at this point you now need to look at your options on the sending end as to how to send such a formatted email - eg, `sendmail`, `mailx`, `mutt`, whatever `mail` points to on your system, etc; this also assumes the (receiving) email client is capable of displaying `MIME` encoded messages)

---

One simple `sendmail` example I've used when sending emails (from linux to Windows/Mac users) where I want the contents of the email to be displayed as fixed-width text:

```
$ subject="this is the subject  of my email"
$ emlist="list_of_email_addresses"
$ mailfile=$(mktemp)

$ echo "Subject: ${subject}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
<html><body><pre>"              >  "${mailfile}"
cat result_new                  >> "${mailfile}"
echo "</pre></body></html>"     >> "${mailfile}"

$ cat ${mailfile} | /usr/sbin/sendmail ${emlist}
$ 'rm' -rf "${mailfile}"
```

If you don't have access to `sendmail` then you may need to do some testing with your mail (sending) program to see how to send a `MIME` encoded message ...